# Edit email using powershell and retain the HTML format

Tags: powershell

Hi I am trying to edit the HTML email template using powershell which has some pictures and colours.
I need to edit and replace some content in email and retain the html body. When i try the below script it's converting to text format

```html
$file= 'FILE PATH '
$outlook= New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$msg= $outlook.createitemfromtemplate($file)
$msg.body= $msg.body -replace "December\d*", "TEST$a"
$msg.saveas($file)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use HTMLBody and not body. Because you are telling it to use plane text in the email rather than HTML. Hope this helps.

```
$file= 'C:\Temp\template.msg'
$outlook= New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$msg= $outlook.createitemfromtemplate($file)
$msg.HTMLbody = $msg.HTMLbody.Replace("color2", "color")
$msg.saveas($file)
#$file | ConvertTo-Html #if needed
```

Test scenario:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwATE.png)

Code was ran:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UQkk.png)

After:

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqCEo.png)

Comment: Hi,Still i face the same issue, I still see the .msg file is converted to text format and all images are been deleted

Comment: Can you please share the file you are trying to edit? When I added $msg.HTMLbody = $msg.HTMLbody -replace "December", "TEST" the email body for template.msg kept its HTML format.

Comment: Sorry, that cannot be shared.

Comment: The Email contains some pictures and and text inside the pictre .Like Some notification email

Comment: I understand, I tested multiple times the code that I provided you. Tested with images, with text and it keeps the html format. Can you please start testing again with a new template.msg, Also try changing only text like my example and see if it works.

Comment: Content is getting replaced inside the email, But the email content will become text and all pictures will get deleted and email converts to TEXT format

Comment: I tried with a picture inside also but it returns all the info correctly. Let's do this, what type of info are you trying to replace in the template: only text or with a picture? In addition did you try to see if you can change only a text as my example ? Also what types of files are you using for the template and the info you are getting it from: .msg or something else ?

Comment: I am trying to replace the content of text , The mail is consist of Diffrent colours and have some pictures.I am not changing any picture .I am only trying to change content of text like"DECEMBER" to "JANUARY" .I am using .msg file to edit and it is saving has .msg file only .But after running script the content will become TEXT format

Comment: I have edited the code above, please check if this is ok for you.

Comment: No, I still face the same issue.

Comment: No, I still face the same issue.If i need to send the test email which i am tryin gto edit how do i do that ?

Comment: So what the script above does is: It replaces the text "color2" with "color" without changing the HTML or removing color, images and etc. I did not get your last question very well. But What you are trying to do is copy and past a completely different body in the template you want or something different? If you need to send an email with powershell: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/send-email-windows-powershell/. Test this create a tamplate.msg and use my script and put a text color2 or whatever text and run the script and see if it changes the html or only the text to something you told it to.

Comment: Yes, it replaces the color2 with "color" with removing all colour background and images in email and changes to TEXt format

Comment: I will retest and see why we get 2 different results.

Comment: I have added the test done by my side, the other part of the email stays the same, but cannot be added as info for security reasons. Please show me how it is with you if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue than I used $mail.Save() after replacing de part I want on html body than everything worked.
Without saving before sending I got an text message rather than html.